# Work using net nanny

Tags: content-security-policy

I went to check my email at work, when I types in my password, net nanny appeared saying Adult/mature content was being seen. I had to click continue in order to go forward and sign out. Even after I clicked sign out the net nanny appeared again saying the same thing and I had to click continue in order to sign out of my email. Does this mean someone from my work will be alerted and be able to see all my personal emails, photos/videos, and history that could get me in trouble? Like an automatic screen reader of my emails?

Comment: Do you access your email using SSL or not?

Comment: What's SSL? I literally just logged on to print something for someone and it popped up when I entered my password that I had adult/mature content. And I couldn't log out unless I clicked continue again by the net nanny pop up. These computers are in a office room for people to use while at the gym.

Comment: There's not enough information here to be able to give you any answer other than "maybe, but probably not".

Comment: I don't think I had my email set on ssl unless it comes like that. Do you think a list of history was given to them of site and comments shared by me with others?

Comment: And since you don't know, there's no way for anyone to answer your question. If you're using SSL, then it's less likely that someone would be able to see the contents of the page (though still not impossible, depending on their setup). Whether anyone actually *does* notice will depend on your company policy - which, again, nobody else can answer.

Comment: @JennyD — when "at work" (in this context), it's extremely likely anything on that computer could be monitored, SSL or not.

Comment: @JoelL **Could** be monitored - yes, absolutely. **Is** actively monitored - not necessarily.

Comment: Expend your question with some 'enviromental details' like:

- OS (or operating System)
- Mail client
- Web mail
- Type of Connection ( pop/imap/smtp/smtps) (2 of them should be used)
- Port numbers used.
- who owns the machine you use?


without such details its impossible to waner your question.

Comment: What is this net nanny thing?

Comment: @SteveDL It's content-filtering software: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_Nanny

Comment: @JennyD  When Net Nanny is involved, SSL is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: if your employer has installed monitoring software on a computer, it's reasonable to assume *anything* you do on that computer could be monitored and recorded.

Answer (score 2):

Net Nanny can be configured to send email alerts to a specific address when it notices a violation. These reports include the URL the user accessed and the category it was blocked for, but not the actual content.

Whether it is configured that way on your site and whether someone actually reads the generated warnings is something you need to find out on your own. But when someone reads them, they are likely used to seeing lots of false positives, because web filter software is notoriously unreliable.

Regarding safety of your personal email: When you are using a computer which is administrated by someone else, you need to be aware that anything you do with it *might* be monitored. When you are at your work computer you can not really have any expectation of privacy. So when you want to do anything at work you don't want the company to know, use a private device.